# Laravel get the content of a translation file as an array

Tags: php, laravel

could you help me with the following question. I need to get the content of a translation file as an array regardless of whether it is a `PHP` file or a `JSON` file.

Suppose I have the following structure in my project:

```
laravel_project/resources/lang/
├── en
├── es
├── file1.php
├── file2.json
...
```

and I have the following method:

```
    public function example()
    {
        dd(__('file1', [], '/'));
    }
```

I get the following result:

```
array:2 [
  "failed" => "These credentials do not match our records."
  "throttle" => "Too many login attempts. Please try again in :seconds seconds."
]
```

Which is great since it is the content of the `file1.php` file, but I wonder how I can get the content of the `file2.json` file in the same way, because when I do the following:

```
    public function example()
    {
        dd(__('file2', [], '/'));
    }
```

I get the following result:

```
"file2"
```

The content of the `file2.json` file is the following:

```
{
    "A": "My string A",
    "B": "My string B"
}
```

I mean, it is not returning the content of the file `file2.json`. Is there an elegant way to achieve what I am trying to do? Basically what I am trying to do is return the content of a translation file regardless of whether it is a `PHP` file or a `JSON` file. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing in Laravel 7x shows that your json file contents can be accessed like:

```
dd(__('*', [], 'file2'));
```

Given this, you would still need to come up with a way to determine if you're accessing a PHP file or a JSON file. You could do something like:

```
public function example($file)
{
    // get JSON contents
    $data = __('*', [], $file);

    // if no JSON contents found, get PHP contents
    if ($data == '*') {
        $data = __($file, [], '/');
    }

    return $data;
}
```

NB: this is using the translator in a way that is undocumented and not intended. There is no guarantee a future "non-breaking" change won't break this.

Another option you have is to extend and override the framework's FileLoader and/or Translator to add in the functionality you're looking for. Bind your override classes into the aliases in the container, and then your custom code will be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. It Works!. I had a hunch that somehow using Laravel Translator class was going to work. You are my savior of the day. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 $yourJsonAsArray = json_decode(implode(file($filename)), true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That's really what I'm trying to avoid. Having to use the native functions of PHP to have to load it, I suppose that in some way using Laravel it can be done, since in the way that I describe above if it loads the files of type PHP.

Comment: Ok, try
`Storage::disk('local')->get($filename);`
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#retrieving-files